# What is the Mehrestellenverfahren of finite difference scheme?

Tags: numerical-methods

When I read the book *A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations* by A. Iserles, in Part II, p.163, there is one method called Mehrestellenverfahren, which is a modified nine-point formula. However, this method is not well known so can anyone tell me what it is? I feel like this method looks so much like a compact finite difference method.

Comment: I think you have misspelled the name of the method. The second "e" shouldn't be there. It's *Mehrstellenverfahren*.

Comment: Also, have you looked up the source cited by Iserles for this method? Namely, *The Numerical Treatment of Differential Equations* by Lothar Collatz.